# How to evaluate the smoothness (flatness) of a curve in python?

Tags: python, scipy

I'm wondering how to evaluate the smoothness of a curve if there's a score function that can be described or rating can be compared with others.

I originally used standard deviation to evaluate the smoothness of the curve before, and it works well when the curve is average on a flat condition. However, if the curve has a slope that makes it goes higher, it can't give an expected result since it may be affected by the maxima or the minimum, but I only want to take the smoothness into my consideration.

Here is an example of my thought:
[image: Graph 1]
[image: Graph 2]
(Only see the green line)
the score or the rate of the green line in the first picture is supposed to be higher since it looks more smoothly than on the second one.

I'm thinking about if I can use the module of Scipy signaling or something else. Please comment to me if you have any ideas, that will help me a lot. So many thanks.

Comment: Could you calculate the standard deviation of the derivative of the lines instead?

Comment: @TomMcLean But my data is discrete, can it do the derivation in python?

Comment: Good alternative would be curvature calculation: https://www.delftstack.com/howto/numpy/curvature-formula-numpy/. 0 curvature means this is straight line

Comment: @tangerine0803 Yes, you can still calculate the derivative of discrete data. see `np.diff` - https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html (Or in the answer below)

Answer (score 3):

There are many different definitions of "smoothness". Depending on what you are looking for, you can use different methods to evaluate the smoothness of your curve.

As Tom suggested, you could evaluate the standard deviation of the derivative.

Another, more mathematically accurate method would be to evaluate the integral of the squared second derivative of your function. See more in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1589338/750929).

[image]

In either case, to evaluate the derivative from a discrete dataset, you can calculate the slope between every two points in your dataset. Thus it would look something like that:

```py
from numpy import diff

y_dataset = [...]
x_dataset = [...]
dy_dx = diff(y_dataset)/diff(x_dataset)
```

or

```py
from numpy import diff

y_dataset = [...]
dx = n
dy_dx = diff(y_dataset)/dx
```

Hope that helps a bit :)

Comment: Thanks for your kindly answer, you really help me :) I'm now trying with Tom's suggestion and your suggestion to calculate the slope. The mathematically way you mentioned, I still do not really understand after checking the link, but maybe I will try to code them with the formula.